# Designer showing image but emulator doesn't windows phone 7.1

Tags: image, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I have created code to show image in panorama page. There is designer of that page showing but when i execute the program with my emulator or on my windows phone 8  they both are doesn't showing that images. Images are edited in paint. what is the resolution to show image perfectly in grid ??

my code is:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem >
            <Grid Margin="0,-120,0,0">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="612" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420" Source="/HubTilesPanorama;component/powers.jpg" Margin="0,102,0,0" />

            </Grid >
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: You have a top margin of -120. Are you sure it does not go outside of the screen?

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on?